# configparser is dropping comments when writing out

Tags: python-2.7

In my Python program, I read a config (in my real code from file), but on writing the comment is gone. How can I keep that in there?

```
import sys
import ConfigParser
import io

sample_config = """
[user01]
name = Sal
# update this value
password = abc123
"""

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.readfp(io.BytesIO(sample_config))
config.set('user01', 'password', '123abc')
config.write(sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
[user01]
name = Sal
password = 123abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [configobj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html) for that it preserves comments when you read and write
the config files:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

sample_config = """
[user01]
name = Sal
# update this value
password = abc123
"""

config = ConfigObj(sample_config.splitlines())
config['user01']['password'] = '123abc'
config.write(sys.stdout)
```